# Reduce relations by utilizing constraints

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I am currently facing the following problem:
I have many sub-concepts of a class A in my ontology, which have an individual relationship to an associated sub-concept of class B. So for each of these concept pairs I have an individual relation. Would it be possible to connect the parent concepts once and additionally define corresponding constraints? (cf. figure)
(Would it be possible to simply give each of these relations the same name, but assign different domains and ranges? [Not to the best of my knowledge.])

[image]

This way the graphical representation and the ontology as a whole would be much tidier, since about ten relations would be omitted. Also, there would be fewer different relation identifiers to remember for the SPARQL queries.

best
Muffex

Comment: *"Would it be possible to simply give each of these relations the same name, but assign different domains and ranges?"* - no, that is not possible. The whole idea of a URI is to be a unique identifier. What you could (and should?) do is to use at least a superproperty, this would at least allow for rather simple querying later on with SPARQL as you can easily refer to all subproperties

Comment: Hey @UninformedUser. Thanks for your answer. I haven't quite figured that out yet. What would this imply for my fictitious example (cf. figure)?

Comment: I think what inferences you want to derive from your ontology should drive your decisions. I.e. knowing that individuals `x1` and `y1` are linked via `screwCapBottle_has_screwCap` a reasoner can infer `x1` is of type `Screw cap bottle` and `y1` of type `Screw cap` whereas knowing `x2` and `y2` are linked via `bottle_has_bottleSeal` a reasoner can at most infer that `x2` is of type `Bottle` and `y2` is of type `BottleSeal`. In the case of `x1` and `y1` the inference will be more precise. The question is what is the needs of your use case?

Comment: Hey @HenrietteHarmse thanks a lot for your answer.
I am not familiar with how reasoners work. However, it is quite important that it is evident that only one unique association is possible here. That's why my question refers to whether there are two ways of modeling. (1) So far I use a single relation for each relation of the subclasses. (2) Would it be possible to connect the superclasses with a relation and additionally use constraints which express a unique association of the subclasses?

Comment: I have tried to show this with my illustration. The left side (1) shows the current model and the right side (2) shows my intendet changes.